Why is my express.render() not doing anything after building?
I have an express server inside my electron-forge app that is supposed to return an ejs template filled out with my users' information. When I call it in development (npm start) it returns as I would expect. However, when I build (npm run make) it suddenly stops working, not giving errors, or crashing my app, just not running the render call it looks like.
I've quadruple checked my includes in forge.config.js so my views are imported, and they show up in my app's resources folder. I also call
expressServer.set("view engine", "ejs");
expressServer.set(
  "views",
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? path.resolve(__dirname, "views")
    : path.resolve(process.resourcesPath, "views")
);

And when I log these in production I get the correct file urls.
I've even simplified my code to where I just want .render to return an error, but even that is not happening:
expressServer.get("/editusers", async (req, res) => {
  const users = getAllUsers();
  log.info("got to here");
  try {
    res.render("test of a random sentence instead of a filename", (err, html) => {
      if (err) {
        log.info(`Error: ${err}`);
      } else {
        log.info(`No error, html: ${html}`);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    log.info(`got error: ${err}`);
    throw new Error(err);
  }
});

gives me Error: Error: Failed to lookup view "test of a random sentence instead of a filename" in views directory when I run it in development (using npm start) but nothing when I build and run...
